# Making friendlier URLs (using htaccess)?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite URLs for some pages on my site, so page.mysite.com would lead to mysite.com/profiles/page

How should  I do it?

Comment: I don't know why this question has got so many downvotes - it looks pretty reasonable to me, albeit short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs of the form http://***page***.mysite.com are subdomains. You cannot configure them using .htaccess alone. You will need to set up a wildcard DNS to point all subdomains at your server. You will also need some sort of wildcard virtual host setup in the apache config of the server.

Once you have that working, take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/vhosts.html from the apache mod_rewrite examples.